# Где найти общепринятые нормы произношения русских слов?

Tags: фонетика

Где я могу увидеть общепринятые нормы произношения русских слов? Существуют ли какие-нибудь словари по этой теме?

Answer (score 2):

Да. конечно. Нормы произношения описаны в орфоэпических словарях. В предисловии - общие правила произношения безударных гласных, нескольких рядом стоящих согласных и т.д. В самом словаре показаны особенности произношения отдельных слов. Акцентологические нормы (ударение) принято указывать во всех словарях.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, разнообразные словари часто противоречат друг другу. Где искать критерии, если даже Д.Лихачёв говорил "одеваю пальто"."Словарь ударений для работников радио и ТВ" часто расходится с "Орфоэпическим словарём русского языка" Аванесова.